# Uniqueness of the Solutions to the Equations of Equilibrium

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, regularity-theory-of-pdes, greens-function

I have to prove uniqueness of solutions to the following problem:

[image]

Since it is a uniqueness problem, I took $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ both  to   be solutions. I replaced them in both the equation and boundary condition and substracted one from the other. So taking $\textbf{w}=\textbf{u}-\textbf{v}$, I have

$$-\nabla^2\textbf{w}-\kappa\nabla\nabla\cdot\textbf{w}=0$$
$$\textbf{w}=\textbf{0}$$

Then I multipled the equation through by $\textbf{w}$ and took the integral to apply the Green's Identity from which I'm finally at

$$\int_\mathbb{R^3}|\nabla\textbf{w}|^2dx=\kappa\int_\mathbb{R^3}\textbf{w}\nabla\nabla\cdot\textbf{w}dx$$

I think I'm supposed to show somehow that $\textbf{w}=\textbf{0}$ everywhere on the domain and not only on the boundary. But I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

First note that you have an error in the sets over which you're integrating.  You multiply by $w$ and integrate over $\Omega$ to get 
$$
\int_{\Omega} | \nabla w|^2 = \kappa \int_{\Omega} w \cdot \nabla (\nabla \cdot w).
$$
Here's a hint for how to conclude.  On the right side you can integrate by parts again:
$$
\int_{\Omega} w\cdot \nabla f = -\int_{\Omega} (\nabla \cdot w) f + \int_{\partial \Omega} f w\cdot n.
$$

Comment: so I've used an identity $\nabla\nabla\cdot w=\nabla\times(\nabla\times w)+\nabla^2w$ and said that since there's no mention of a rotation, $\nabla\times w=0$. do you think it's correct?

Comment: No.  Just integrate by parts as in my hint.